# how to group products to display in page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to ask for your help to make some code modifications to some code I am working on.

Currently the code displays 'x' number of products on a page in the fashion of:

box 1 (product id 140)

price $10

box 2 (product id 140)

price $10

box 3 (product id 143) - different Id

price $20

Order Sub-Total: $40.00

**CODE**

```
            <div class="yourorder">
                @foreach (var prod in Model.Products)
                {
                    for (var i = 0; i < prod.Count; i++)
                    {
                        <div data-index="@i" data-type="product" data-id="@prod.ID" data-multiple="@prod.Multiple" data-multiplecatid="@prod.MultipleCategoryID">                                
                            @{Html.RenderAction("ShoppingCartProduct", "ShoppingCart", new { id = prod.ID });}
                            <div class="shippingArea">
                                <div class="shippingPickerLabel">Use this shipping address:</div>
                                <div>
                                    <select class="shippingPicker" data-type="prod" data-id="@(prod.ID)">
                                        <option value="-1">Add New</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <br />
                    <hr />
                    }
                }
                <div class="totals" style="font-weight:normal;margin-top:20px;">

                    @if (Model.TotalPriceFrom == Model.TotalPriceTo)
                    {
                        <div><strong>Order Sub-Total:</strong> $<span class="grandTotal">@Model.TotalPriceTo.ToString("0.00")</span></div>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <div><strong>Order Sub-Total:</strong> $<span class="grandTotal">@Model.TotalPriceFrom.ToString("0.00") - $@Model.TotalPriceTo.ToString("0.00")</span></div>
                    }
                </div>
        </div>
```

The Price is calculated in a PartialView named "ShoppingCartProduct". the code that does that:

**CODE**

```
    <div class="shoppingCartPrice">
    @if (Model.Prod.HasRange && Model.Prod.WeightFrom.HasValue && Model.Prod.WeightTo.HasValue)
    {
        if (Model.Prod.UnitID.HasValue)
        {
            <div>$@Model.Prod.Price.Value.ToString("0.00") per @Model.UnitName</div>
        }
        <div>Price: $@((Model.Prod.Price.Value * Model.Prod.WeightFrom.Value).ToString("0.00")) - $@((Model.Prod.Price.Value * Model.Prod.WeightTo.Value).ToString("0.00"))</div>
        <div style="display:none;" class="minPrice">@((Model.Prod.Price.Value * Model.Prod.WeightFrom.Value).ToString("0.00"))</div>
        <div style="display:none;" class="maxPrice">@((Model.Prod.Price.Value * Model.Prod.WeightTo.Value).ToString("0.00"))</div>
    }
    else
    {
        <div>Price: $@Model.Prod.Price.Value.ToString("0.00")</div>
        <div style="display:none;" class="minPrice">@((Model.Prod.Price.Value).ToString("0.00"))</div>
        <div style="display:none;" class="maxPrice">@((Model.Prod.Price.Value).ToString("0.00"))</div>
    }
</div>
```

I need help in making it calculate different and display different too.

Like:

box 1 qty 2 (products with same id)

price each $10

sub-total $20.00

box 2 qty 1 (products with different id)

price $20

sub-total $20.00

Order Sub-Total: $40.00

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem not that long ago. We solved it by using a cookie.
The products were loaded from an SQL server, but for each product we increased it's ID with 1, so the product ID ranged from 1 to X. With the thought of a huge webshop, we made this number 4 charters long, so: 0001.

Then we just read the product ID into a string and added the quantity behind that, so a string of 6 chars. Then:

```
int count = Response.Cookie["producten"].Length / 6

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
//paste your string decoder here to sort out the product ID and the quantity
Panel p = new Panel();
p.ID = i;
p.CssClass = [your cssclass]
//paste here code for the rest of your div
cartdiv.Controls.Add(p);
}
```

By doing this, the code generates a div (or anything else you'd want) with unique ID's and the same Class, for each product.